# String literals in C++ with _T macro

Tags: c++, windows, string

What is the difference (if any) between this

```
_T("a string")
```

and

```
_T('a string')
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `_T` isn't a standard part of C++. I've added the "windows" tag to your question.

Now, the difference between these is that the first is correct and the second is not. In C++, `'` is for quoting *single characters*, and `"` is for quoting strings.

Comment: Accepted for most concise explanation of the question. Many thanks

Comment: You actually can have multi-char character literals, but the value is implementation defined. Most compilers I know of concatenate the character values into a single value. E.g. '1234' == 0x31323334.

Answer (score 3):

The second is wrong. You are placing a string literal in between single quotes.

Comment: Yes, since the single quote marks are used for characters only.

Answer (score 3):

`'a string'` is a so-called "multicharacter literal". It has type `int`, and an implementation-defined value. This is `[lex.ccon]` in the standard.

I don't know what values MSVC gives to multicharacter literals, and I don't know for sure what the MS-specific `_T` macro ends up doing with it, but I expect you get a narrow multicharacter literal on narrow builds, and a wide multicharacter literal on wide builds. The prefix `L` is the same for strings and character literals.

It's wrong, anyway: multicharacter literals are pretty much useless and certainly are no substitute for strings. `"a string"` is a string literal, which is what you want.

Comment: `_T` may stick an `L` before the `'c-char-sequence'`. Its value still is implementation-defined.

Comment: @MSalters: yes, that's what I expect, `_T(x)` will be defined to `x` in narrow builds or `L ## x` in wide builds. But I don't know, it might do something more complicated sometimes. As you say, the actual value is implementation-defined either way. Maybe with C++11 support will come options where `_T` adds `u` instead of `L`, which case `u'a string'` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

You use `''` for single character and `""` for strings. `_T('a string')` is wrong and its behaviour is compiler-specific.

In case of MSVC it uses first character only. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    if (_T('a string') == _T('a'))
        std::cout << (int)'a' << " = " << _T('a');
}
```

output: `97 = 97`

Comment: Actually, the value of `'a string'` is not defined. Some implementations use the first, some the last, and other choices (e.g. `\0`) would be legal too.

Comment: @MSalters : You say it's compiler - specific ?

Comment: Yes. 2.14.3/1 says it's implementation-defined.

Comment: And `'a string'` doesn't necessarily use only one character. You've take the least significant bits by casting to `char`, but you might well find that `'a string' != 'a'` even though `((char) 'a string') == 'a'`.

Comment: Also trying to write something like `if ('a string' == 'a')` ends with `error C2015: too many characters in constant`.

Comment: @SteveJessop : output of `std::cout << L'a string';` is also `97`

Comment: @LihO: ah, so MSVC accepts it as a wide multicharacter (`L'a string'`), but not as a narrow one. And your edit proves that it ignores all but the first character. IIRC, gcc uses 4 bytes of the literal to give 32 bits of integer value, although I literally don't care what order it puts them.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotations are primarily used when denoting a single character:

```
char c = 'e' ;
```

Double quotations are used with strings and output statements:

```
string s = "This is a string";
cout << "Output where double quotations are used.";
```